# How do I get Applescript to hold down a key?

Tags: automation, applescript, minecraft

I'm making a Applescript program to automate tedious parts of some games. I just need to know how to make the program hold down keys for a few seconds. Those keys being W,A,S,D and Shift. I'd be really nice if somebody can help me out.

Comment: Pure AppleScript can only hold down the modifier keys ⌘⌥⇧⌃.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point. Would a copy of the rising edge key not be enough.

for an example:
check rising edge on keys -> put a flag for each key.
if all flag ON wait x seconds.
Reset flag.

Normally you don't try to hold the system, you just read the flow and use what you need to do something. Holding the system frequently result in a crash or a loss of informations.